# Third level categories Url is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, category-tree

```
Shop 
   Colors 
       Rushmore 
       Boston Mill 
       Little Cottonwood
```

This my category structure. But **child category URLs are not working**.

> Link: mysite.com/shop/colors/rushmore.html

Comment: installed any extensions related to menu?

Comment: @shiwani Do Re-indexing, clear cache and try again

Comment: is it going to 404?

Comment: Please check in
admin >> Marketing >> SEO & Search >> URL Rewrites
Here check your url does it exist?